# Normalize Machine Learning Inputs

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a set of inputs that has 5000ish features with values that vary from 0.005 to 9000000. Each of the features has similar values (a feature with a value of 10ish will not also have a value of 0.1ish)

I am trying to apply linear regression to this data set, however, the wide range of input values is inhibiting effective gradient descent.

What is the best way to handle this variance? If normalization is best, please include details on the best way to implement this normalization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply perform it as a pre-processing step. You can do it as following:

1) Calculate mean values for each of the features in the training set and store it. Be careful, do not mess up feature mean and sample mean, so you will have a vector of size [number_of_features (5000ish)].

2) Calculate std. for each feature in the training set and store it. Size of [number_of_feature] as well

3) Update each training and testing entry as:

updated = (original_vector - mean_vector)/ std_vector

That's it!

The code will look like:

```
# train_data shape [train_length,5000] 
# test_data        [test_length, 5000]
mean = np.mean(train_data,1)
std = np.std(train_data,1)

normalized_train_data = (train_data - mean)/ std
normalized_test_data = (test_data - mean)/ std
```